# Remove Search and Go Button on keyboard in iOS web app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing a PhoneGap app using JQuery Mobile.

I change pages based on buttons and links that are clicked within the app.  All of my views are encapsulated in a single index.html page.  Different pages are broken up by div data role like so:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="view1"></div>

 <div data-role="page" id="view2"></div>
```

When a button is clicked the app moves the next view with:

```
   $.mobile.changePage("#search2_1");
```

The problem is when a user is typing in a text box.  The keyboard pops up with either the "Go" or "Search" buttons available.  If the user clicks this, they bypass the javascript function that moves them to the next page and are inadvertently sent back to the root of the app.

Is there anyway to disable or remove these buttons or even have these buttons trigger the change page function?

*note: since this is a PhoneGap app I am limited in what I can do in Objective-C and I am focusing on doing this within the web page.

Comment: are your input elements inside a form element?

Comment: yes they are.  Is there an element i can add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your elements are inside a form element the user submits the form by pressing the search or go button, which will reload the page.

you need to cancel the form submit.

This would look something like this in jquery:

```
$("yourform").submit(function(){
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of the question, this is what I did:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#button').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```

This prevents the default submit, and instead triggers the action you want.